# Show data to view with one to many relationship in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have 2 tables:

```
Type: id, name
Question: id, content, type_id
```

I've show data with filter function but when I'm trying to show type name and level name, I got this error

> Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

When I dump($data), i got this:

```
LengthAwarePaginator {#217 ▼
  #total: 6
  #items: Collection {#229 ▼
    #items: array:6 [▼
      0 => Question {#230 ▶}
      1 => Question {#231 ▶}
      2 => Question {#232 ▶}
      3 => Question {#233 ▶}
      4 => Question {#234 ▶}
      5 => Question {#235 ▶}
    ]
  }
  #path: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/test"
  #query: array:1 [▶]
  ...
}
```

This is my Model
Question.php

```
protected $table = 'question';
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function types()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Type::class,'type_id','id');
    }
```

Type.php

```
protected $table = 'type';
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['type_id'];

    public function questions(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Question::class);
    }
```

TestController.php

```
public function getTest(Request $request){
        $types = Type::all();
        $model = Question::where('id', '>', 0);

        if (isset($request->type))
            $model = $model->where('type_id', $request->type);

        $data = $model->paginate(15)->appends(request()->query());

        return view('filter', compact( 'data', 'request', 'types'));
    }
```

And this is my view

```
<form method="get">
    <select name="type" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="">All types</option>
        @foreach ($types as $item)
            <option value="{{ $item->id }}" @if ($request->type == $item->id) selected @endif>{{ $item->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</form>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Content</th>
        <th>Type</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach ($data as $q)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $q->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $q->content }}</td>
            <td>{{ $q->type_id->name }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <td>{{ $q->type_id->name }}</td>
```

Check this line, There is no relation with type model.

```
$q->type->name
```

Maybe you want to do something like that, but you can do this with `hasMany`, you need to use one-to-one relation

Answer (score 1):

I would have done this way

[image]

ModelQuestion:

```
class ModelQuestion extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $table = 'question';
    protected $guarded = [];


    public function scopeIdGreaterThan($query, $id){
        return $query->where('id','>', $id);
    }

    public function scopeOfType($query, $type){
        return $query->where('type_id', '=', $type);
    }


    public function type(){
        return $this->hasOne(ModelType::class, 'id', 'type_id');
    }
}
```

ModelType:

```
class ModelType extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $table = 'type';
    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

Function in controller:

```
public function getQuestions(Request $request) {
    $type = (isset($request->type)) ? $request->type : 0;
    $perPage = 15;

    $data = ModelQuestion::with('type')->idGreaterThan(0);

    //whatever condition you want
    if ($type !== 0) $data->ofType($type);

    $data = $data->paginate($perPage);
    return response()->json($data);
}
```

Output : https://pastebin.com/JdSq5kSb

In your blade you can simply get like this:

```
$data[i]->content
$data[i]->type->name
```

Note : I don't know what are you appending in `$request->query`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys. I found this solution:

```
@foreach ($data as $q)
    <?php $typeName = App\Type::find($q->type_id); ?>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $q->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $q->content }}</td>
        <td>{{ $typeName->name }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```